# SQL, Using LIKE operator to select from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I need to select from `table1.cloumn` when its value contain a value from `table2.column`

I was trying this:

```
select * from Products1 where sku like '%' + (select sku from Products2) + '%'
```

Comment: Fix your data model so you are not storing lists of skus in a single column.  That is not the SQL way to store data.

Comment: I am not storing in one col, it's only for the example of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use `exists` with a subquery.

```
select * 
from Products1 t1
where exists(
    select 1
    from Products2 t2
    WHERE t1.sku like '%' + t2.sku+ '%' 
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aed41ca154ca6ca1e320046756630b51)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the other answers is to use a `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT P1.*
FROM Products1 P1
INNER JOIN Products2 on P1.sku like '%' + P2.sku+ '%'
```

Comment: Will however return duplicates if Products2 contains duplicates.

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about duplicates :-)

Comment: Yes, just the partial comparison of strings.

Answer (score 1):

use simple like

```
select t1.* 
from Products1 t1
where t1.sku like '%'+ (
      select t2.sku from Products2 t2
         )+ '%'
```

[sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=affaa4a0dd60bff78a8370e577c2b6b0)